# Daemonize a PHP script with the option to kill it

Tags: php, linux, background, laravel-4, daemon

I have a script that should start running when the user presses the start button on my application. This script takes a couple of variables given by the user like configuration etc. This script should then be running until the user clicks the stop button again.

Now I have been doing my research and found out that daemonizing the script would be the best option but now I have a couple of problems.

Which daemon PHP package do I use for this kind of process? How do I pass in the variables? How do I kill the script once the user commands it to?

I am using a Digital Ocean VPS to host my application and I'll be using it to host all the processes of the Daemons. I'm using Ubuntu and as a PHP framework I'm am using Laravel 4.

Comment: As 3mpty says, consider a job queuing system. As well as Rabbit, look at Gearman. These tend to get started on a per-item basis, so there's generally no need for a separate kill command, though a worker may exit early if you code it that way.

Comment: I have to take a look at Gearman, is it easy to integrate into Laravel?

Comment: I don't know Laravel. However, Gearman is very easy to integrate into PHP, and Laravel is written in PHP, so I would say yes `:)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is other option - you can use async messaging like RabbitMQ. It's very easy to use, massive amount of tutorials on website: [RabbitMQ tutorials](http://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html).

Your worker script need to listen for user commands and process enabled tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the PHP-Daemon package sa can't tell you if that is a suitable solution. However I can show you a solution we used I've used before. You should modify it somewath to make it fit to your own needs.

```
// Let the script may run forever, maybe you want another limit
set_time_limit(0);
// Keep the script running even if the browser disconnects
ignore_user_abort(true);

// Create a temporary file that can tell you the user clicked stop
$tmpFile = tempnam('/tmp', 'mydaemon-');

// Ouptput buffering
ob_start();

// echo some output, including a stop-button with a link to a PHP-script
// that will delete the $tmpFile. It's up to you to implement stop.php
echo '<a href="stop.php?id='.$tmpFile.'">stop</a>';

// Make sure to turn off all output-buffering
while(ob_get_level() > 1) {
    ob_end_flush;
}
// Store output of last buffer in a string
$fullContent = ob_get_clean();

// Tell the browser to stop loading the page
$fullContent .= '<script type="text/javascript">window.stop();</script>';

// Close the session (if you have one), otherwise stop-action can't
// be opened
session_close();

// Sent output to the browser
header("Content-Length: ".strlen($fullContent));
header('Connection: close');          
echo $fullContent;
// Force all output be sent
flush();


// Time-consuming script, regurarly check if the $tmpFile exists,
// if not, stop execution
while(true) {
    clear_stat_cache();
    if ( ! file_exists($tmpFile)) {
        break;
    }
    sleep(1);
}
```